# Is "setting" UI implemented by table view in iphone/touch/ipad?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I want my app's setting UI feel consistent with iphone's internal setting UI. It looks like it's implemented by a table view with sections to group the setting items together. Am I correct?

refer to:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNVyO.png

Is it implemented by a table view with hard coded cells and sections or is it build by interface builder? If it is built by IB, how to design the sections?

thanks

-Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up about how UITableView Work, You will need a UITableViewDataSource.
The datasource tells the table how many sections and cells there are in the table view.
Then the UITableViewDelegate will handle any selecte rows:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableView.html

Answer (score 3):

you might want to look at something like InAppSettingsKit, an open source framework that duplicates the settings app feel in your application.

if you want to create it yourself you'd just set the ui table view style to UITableViewStyleGrouped