# Building forms using UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i found building forms very disturbing and problematic with UITableView (the kind of forms you find in settings, cell usually got a label + control like uiswitch or uitextfield).
Is there any framework for making it easy to build them? (In app settings kit kind of does it, but i wondered if there's something dedicated for this)
best
peter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "setting" UI implemented by table view in iphone/touch/ipad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700761/is-setting-ui-implemented-by-table-view-in-iphone-touch-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework for building Forms and Table views you can check it here : [Sensible Cocoa](http://www.sensiblecocoa.com/)

Comment: Yes It is really cool indeed, I don't know other opensource alternatives.